# Issuer in a SAML failure response

Tags: java, saml, saml-2.0

On the IDP side, I'm generating and sending a SAML failure response when authentication fails.

From the SAML spec (https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/35711/sstc-saml-core-errata-2.0-wd-06-diff.pdf), I see that issuer is an optional attribute in a response. However, the SP requires this information.

In case of a success response, we send the issuer as

> ```
> <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"> 
> --the Issuer URI here-- 
> </saml:Issuer>
> ```

My question is what should be the namespace URI in a failure response?

Comment: What makes you think it should be different from 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion' ?

Comment: @Hintham Since this is a failure response, I do not have an assertion block in the response. Hence the question.

Comment: The absence of the assertion block has nothing to do with the `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion` namespace. The authentication response status is indicated in the `<StatusCode>` element.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Hintham. I do have a status block with error status codes. I'm new to SAML, it will be very helpful if you can explain the significance of the namespace here. What does it indicate?

Comment: In xml a namespace uniquely identifies an element, in this case the `<Issuer>` element. See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace). It is just a qualifier, it doesn't imply anything.

Comment: Thanks @Hintham. This is very helpful.